# Using ml-engine batch predict via REST API

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

The documentation says Batch predict get input data from and put results to cloud storage. Considering this, am I able to perform batch predict via REST API call and if so, how will it look like?

Much thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform batch prediction on Cloud ML Engine, this is our documentation: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/batch-predict

The api allows for input and output data on google cloud storage.